# [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCredential]: make sure the assembly containing this type is loaded

Tags: sql-server, powershell, powershell-2.0

I wrote a PowerShell script which can connect to SQL Server by using a secure connection string. I've tested this on my local PC and it works perfectly. But once I ran this script on server, it gave me the following error:

> Cannot find type [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCredential]: make sure the assembly containing this type is loaded.

Both machines (local and server) have .Net Framework 4.5 installed. Both connect to the same SQL Server. Both are PowerShell version 2.0. Local machine is Window 7 while Server is Window Server 2008 R2.

In the scripts, I've included Assembly loaded.

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load("Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo,Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=Neutral,PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91") 
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load("Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlEnum,Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=Neutral,PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91") 
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load("Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo,Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=Neutral,PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91")
```

Comment: The `SqlCredential` class is in the `System.Data` namespace, not in the `Microsoft.SqlServer` namespace. I don't see you loading that assembly (`[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Data')`). Besides, how are we supposed to reproduce your problem from the tiny snippet you posted? Please make your sample code [minimal, complete, and verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Does the Server have the same .Net version as your workstation? is the assembly included in the .Net framework or does it need to be installed by a management pack or other installer.

Your code isn't native PowerShell code, You cannot expect it to work everywhere. It seems that you are loading a library that isn't installed on the server but is installed on your workstation.